# add javascript dependencies like java dependencies in maven 2?

Tags: javascript, maven-2, web-frameworks

I'm using apache maven for build project, so i want to add  my dependency javascript frameworks automatically  based  their version , organizing  javascript frameworks , and  download  only  modifiying  label version . 
Exist some plugin similar like java dependencies or alternative with maven ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is standard way of doing this using a feature of the servlet api version 3.
Any jar can expose web resources (javascripts, css, images, etc.) that are located under META-INF/resources.

To solve your problem I would create a maven project of type "jar" for every javascript framework that you want to re-use in your webapp projects.

The only caveat is that the servlet-api v3 requires Tomcat 7, which in turn requires Java 6, but this is usually not a problem.

See this blog:
http://alexismp.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/web-inflib-jarmeta-infresources/

Servlet api 3 reference:
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/

Comment: Thanks for comment, so another alternative i found , using [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)  and bower get all dependencies, i'm doing SPA application using angular and the dependencies problem is fix :D .

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to include javascript frameworks as `<dependency>` via WebJars:
http://www.webjars.org/documentation

You could then include e.g. AngularJs like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

WebJars are also hosted on maven central repository:
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.webjars.bower%7Cangularjs%7C1.5.0-rc.1%7Cjar